# How can I check if a doctrine entity has a oneToOne mapped entity?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use doctrine, `User` and `Info` entities are `OneToOne` to each other, When I call user entity, first I want to check if that entity has a info or not, if has it, update it, if doesn't have it, create a info entity for that user.

I have this hasser method in my User entity:

```
public function hasInfo() {  
       return $this->info instanceof Info;
}
```

Then in my script I have:

```
$user = $em->find(User.....);
if ($user->hasInfo()) {
    $info = $user->getInfo();
    $something = $info->getSomething();
} else {
    $info = new Info;
    $info->setUser($user);
}
```

But I still get entity `Info` not found error. I did a print debug and noticed it never goes to else clause even if it doesn't have info so I get entity `Info` not found error. What wrong I did in my script above?

This one works neither:

```
$user = $em->find(User...);
$Info = $user->getInfo();
if ($info !== null) {
...
```

It always assumes `User` has a `Info` and never goes to else clause. There is no such problem for other mappings than `OneToOne`.

EDIT1: I guess this should because that both entities are mapped by identifiers of each other (as they are one to one) rather than the owning side having a FK? Should be that the issue?

EDIT2: Here are my mappings, I don't use annotation but php mapping:

User entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'info',
    'targetEntity' => 'Info',
    'mappedBy' => 'user',
    'cascade' => array( 
        0 => 'remove', 
        1 => 'persist', 
    ),
    'joinColumns' => array( 
        0 => array( 
            'name' => 'id',
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'nullable' => true,
            'onDelete' => 'cascade',
            'columnDefinition' => NULL,
        ), 
    )
));
```

Info entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'user',
    'targetEntity' => 'User',
    'inversedBy' => 'info',
    'joinColumns' => array( 
        0 => array( 
            'name' => 'id',
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'nullable' => true,
            'columnDefinition' => NULL,
        )
    )
));
```

As they are oneToOne, the PK of info entity is PK of user entity too.

with an empty Info table. it never goes to else clause.

```
// search by identifier:
$info = $em->find("Info", 1);
if ($info !== null) {
    print("yes");
} else  {
    print("no");
}
```

But if I use findOneBy it works fine! what is the problem?

```
$info = $em->getRepository('Info')->findOneBy(array('id' => 1));
```

why cannot I use find() as this is just identifier?

Here is my identifer definition:

```
$metadata->mapField(array(   'fieldName' => 'id',
  'columnName' => 'id',
  'type' => 'integer',
  'nullable' => false,
  'options' => 
  array(
       'unsigned' => true,
  ),
  'id' => true,
));
```

Comment: @Wilt I updated the post to add my mappings.

Comment: @Wilt When I removed joinColumns from Info and only have it in User, still the same if statement problem above happens. please advice.

Comment: @Wilt I apologize, I meant hasInfo(), I edited my question, please advice.

Comment: @Wilt I exacly removed joinCloumns from Info and kept it in User as you said. Now I need to $info = $em->find("Info", 1); but there is no info with identifer 1 so in if statement it should go to ($info === null) clause but it goes to ($info !== null) clause! Why?

Comment: I answered your question below. Please remove all comments, they are not relevant to other users...

Comment: @Wilt That's definitely did not help the problem of IF statement even with your changes.

Comment: Did you update your database schema?

Comment: @Wilt obviously yes.

Comment: So what is the exact error? And in what class and on what line is this error thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with php mapping. But your mappings are wrong. You have two options.

### 1) `User` is owning side

`User` entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'info',
    'targetEntity' => 'Info',
    'inversedBy' => 'user',
    'joinColumns' => array( 
        0 => array( 
            'name' => 'info_id', // <--------------- info_id
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'nullable' => true,
            'onDelete' => 'cascade',
            'columnDefinition' => NULL,
        )
    )
));
```

`Info` entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'user',
    'targetEntity' => 'User',
    'mappedBy' => 'info'
));
```

### 2) `Info` is owning side

`User` entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'info',
    'targetEntity' => 'Info',
    'mappedBy' => 'info'
));
```

`Info` entity:

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne(array(
    'fieldName' => 'user',
    'targetEntity' => 'User',
    'inversedBy' => 'info'
    'joinColumns' => array( 
        0 => array( 
            'name' => 'user_id', // <--------------- user_id
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'nullable' => true,
            'onDelete' => 'cascade',
            'columnDefinition' => NULL,
        )
    )
));
```